# Jquery run focusout function without child elements

Tags: jquery

I have a live ajax search but when I click outside of searchbar, ajax search doesnt close. So I am using the focusout function but when I click ajax body, focusout function is running. I need run focusout function without child elements.

```
$("#ajaxsearch").focusout(function(){
      $("#d_ajax_search_results").hide();
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have an event listener listening on a click on `<body>` element like so

```
$('body').on('click', function(){
    $("#d_ajax_search_results").hide();
});
```

even better would be if you open your searchbar add a class to body. So the body element will look something like

```
<body class="search-bar-open">
```

if the user hides or closes the searchbar you remove the class again. you can use `toggle()` or `addClass() / removeClass()` if you do that you can change

```
$('body').on('click', function(){
```

to

```
$('body.search-bar-open').on('click', function(){
```

then this event will only fire if the search bar is open.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `focusout` you should try this way:

```js
const input = document.getElementById('ajaxsearch');

input.addEventListener('focusin', (e) => {
  console.log('focusin');
});

input.addEventListener('focusout', (e) => {
  console.log('focusout');
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="ajaxsearch" />
```

Alternate way is `focus()` / `blur()` in `jQ`

Answer (score 1):

use `blur` event

```
$("#ajaxsearch").blur(function(){
     $("#d_ajax_search_results").hide();
});
```